# How to sort 2 arrays by the value

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array ( 
[order] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 )
[eventid] => Array ( [0] => id_1 [1] => id_2 )
 )
```

Now I would like to get:

```
Array ( 
[order] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
[eventid] => Array ( [0] => id_2 [1] => id_1 )
)
```

Basically I would like to sort arrays by value of order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use the `usort` function to be able to do this. (See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php))

I would recommend another Array structure though, something like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [order] => 2, [eventid] => id_x )
[1] => Array ( [order] => 1, [eventid] => id_y )
)
```

Then you could a function like this one to sort your array (PHP 5.3 or greater):

```
function array_sort_by(&$array, $key, $descending = false) {
    $sortByKey =
        function ($a, $b) use ($key, $descending) {
            if ($a[$key] === $b[$key]) {
                return 0;
            }
            $return = $a[$key] < $b[$key] ? -1 : 1;
            return ($descending ? -1 * $return : $return);
        };

    usort($array, $sortByKey);
}
```

You would then call the following:

```
array_sort_by($yourArray, 'order');
```

Comment: Love you! I had to change some of attributes in html form to change the array layout but now it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php). While it can cover your case, usort might be a better solution in the long run.

```
$arr = Array ( 
     "order" => Array ( 0 => 6, 1 => 1,2=>43),
     "eventid" => Array ( 0 => 5, 1 => 1,2=>54,3=>0)
 ); 

foreach ($arr as $key => &$value) {
 asort($value);
}
```